# Delete to ; if exists, otherwise to end of line

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, vimrc, cursor-motions

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> C ct;
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> D dt;
```

These two are quite useful, but sometimes there is no `;` after the cursor and then `D` doesn't do anything. And then I have to *press 3 keys to delete `t$`*. (!)

How to check if the last action (i.e. `Dt;`) didn't change anything, and in that case, execute something else (`Dt$`)?
or
How how to check if there's a semicolon *after* the cursor and do `Dt;`, otherwise `Dt$`?

Comment: Actually it only needs 2 characters, you can just do d$ instead of dt$

Comment: @f41lurizer or `D` instead of `d$`; it's alllmost possible to do with `d/;\|$` but the end-of-line matching is a bit weird. "Delete to end of line" does exactly that, "delete to (search end of line)" leaves the last character.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler you made me feel stupid... it had been so simple!  There's no problem with your suggestion - if you add a `x` to the mapping after the search, it will delete the last character, too. And, in order not to delete the `;`, if matched, you'll use lookahead. I think you should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <expr> C (getline('.')[getpos('.')[2]:] =~ ';')? "ct;" : "c$"
```

- `<expr>` allows us to do conditional mapping
- `getline('.') =~ ';'` searches the current line for a semicolon
- `getpos('.')[2]` finds the column that the cursor is on and only searches after it